# AngularJs PayPal Express Checkout 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error

Tags: angularjs, paypal, cors, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to setup a payment for my angularjs app, and I used `paypal` and started with this [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/).

Here's my `http` reuqest.

```
    var req = {
        url: "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp",
        USER: email,
        PWD: pwd,
        SIGNATURE: sign,
        VERSION: 93,
        METHOD: "SetExpressCheckout",
        PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION: "SALE",
        PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: price,
        PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE: "USD",
        RETURNURL: returnUrl,
        CANCELURL: cancelUrl
    }
    $http(req).then(function(response){
        console.log("PAYPAL SUCCESS", response);
    }, function(error){
        console.log("PAYPAL ERROR", error);
    })
```

And here's the error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Hi, You have a (CORS)[http://enable-cors.org] issue. 
Most of the times this is a server issue, but you might miss a header that is required by paypal

Comment: Hello @SanderElias Im doing this request right from the angular app itself. Is there maybe a chance that it's causing that?

Comment: Yes, I'm not that intimate with the paypal api, but it may put a limit of how it is being used in a browser. Doing this server-side will not cause issues like this.

Comment: I thought so, thanks @SanderElias Maybe you know an angular module that can have an express-checkout payment mode. Many thanks.

Comment: I know this one: https://github.com/visla/paypal-express-checkout
No personal experience with it however.

Comment: A good starting point. Thanks :) @SanderElias